# False screenwidth return javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, screen

For some reason when I request the screenWidth from the scene with getWindow().getWidth() It returns a width bigger then the actual widht. Anyone got any clues as to why?

```
public Pane getStackPane(double screenWidht, double screenHeight) {
        double width;
        double height;
        double d;
        for (int i = 0; i < panes.size(); i++) {
            d = (double)i;
            width = screenWidht - d * (screenWidht / 6);
            height = screenHeight - d * (screenHeight / 6);
            panes.get(i).setPrefSize(width, height);
            panes.get(i).setMinHeight(height);
            panes.get(i).setMinWidth(width);
            panes.get(i).setMaxHeight(height);
            panes.get(i).setMaxWidth(width);
        }
        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
        stackpane.getChildren().addAll(panes);
        return stackpane;
    }
```

Example shown in image.

[image: example]

Comment: Where is the call to `getWindow.getWidth()`?

Comment: Also: Are you sure it's the window's width you want to know. That one includes decorations (the scene size does not).

Comment: Even if that would solve it I would still like to know why the width is off since I don't have any decorations on the side, or could perhaps the shadow also count which is behind the window?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but please provide something to reproduce your problem as with your example I can create everything(failing as well as working). Anyways: I'd rather not mix up screencoordinates and local coordinates - they may not be the same.